# Visually identifying audio noise

Tags: python, noise, spectrogram

I have an audio file consisted of a sole 440 Hz sinusoidal wave, which can be heard [here](https://voca.ro/1mpGWvyzntnE).

After some manipulation, I've added a noise to it, resulting in a second audio file, avilable [here](https://voca.ro/1hnILjMxV2Nf).

The noise is pretty noticeable with the human ear (especially when using earphones), so I wanted to visually evidence this noise as well, for a printed document.

To achieve this, I tried plotting the FFT and the Mel Spectrogram of both audios, using the Python code below:

```
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft

def mel_spectrogram(audio, sample_rate, name):
    mel_spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=audio, sr=sample_rate)
    librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(mel_spectrogram,ref=np.max), sr=sample_rate, hop_length=512, y_axis='mel',x_axis='time')
    plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
    plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
    plt.ylabel("Frequency [Hz]")
    plt.savefig('../charts/melspectrogram_' + name + '.png')
    print('### SUCCESFULLY GENERATED MEL SPECTROGRAM CHART FOR: ' + name)
    plt.clf()

def fft_plot(audio, sample_rate, name):
  N = len(audio)    # Number of samples
  T = 1/sample_rate # Period
  y_freq = fft(audio)
  domain = len(y_freq) // 2
  x_freq = np.linspace(0, sample_rate//2, N//2)
  plt.plot(x_freq, abs(y_freq[:domain]))
  plt.xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")
  plt.ylabel("Amplitude |X(t)|")
  plt.savefig('../charts/fft_' + name + '.png')
  print('### SUCCESFULLY GENERATED FFT CHART FOR: ' + name)
  plt.clf()

FILENAMES = ['440Hz.wav','440Hz_noise.wav']

for filename in FILENAMES:
    signal, sample_rate = librosa.load('../arquivos/' + filename)
    fft_plot(signal, sample_rate, filename)
    mel_spectrogram(signal, sample_rate, filename)
```

This code results in the figures shown below, where a) and c) are of the noisy audio; and b) and d) are of the clear audio file.

As there is no significant differences in these plots, I imagine these are not the adequate tools to visually evidence the added noise. How could I make it noticeable that my treatment  on the audio added a noise?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! I can't hear any difference between your two MP3 files. What should I be hearing?

Comment: If you do phase cancellation (cancel the original from noised signal) your resulting signal has quite low level (audacity shows below -48dB) . So, if you change plot scales a bit you might see some differences.

Comment: @PeterK. There is a static noise throughout the second audio file. Indeed, I can only hear it with an earphone on. I should correct that in the original post

Comment: I'd like to add that we're comparing quantized audio – MP3 to be precise, which will gladly mask any audible differences -48 dB  below a tone. So, John, please put something losslessly compressed somewhere – FLAC, for example. It's possible that you observed more difference than we are able to observe, because by design, MP3 would suppress that noise.

Comment: That may be the case @MarcusMüller. Thank you for noting that. I am in fact using wav format, but it seems that the website I used for uploading the files automatically converted them to mp3. However, I have followed Juha's recommendation of phase cancellation and achieved my goals. I appreciate everyone's efforts!

Comment: @JohnCalms ah, you or Juha could put a finishing touch on this question then by posting what you did as answer (answering your own question is totally OK). That would allow you to mark the question as answered, **and** it might help people in the future that find your question

Comment: @JohnCalms, may you write the answer (my technical English poor :( so, it takes an hour to write a clear answer ... ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I make it noticeable that my treatment on the audio added a noise?

Spectral analysis will do the trick, if you do it correctly. Here is an example of using Welch's method power spectral density estimator at an FFT length of $N_{FFT} = 16384$ normalized to 0dB at the peak frequency.

[image]

There are a few things we can take from this picture.

1. The "clean" sine wave isn't all that clean. Most of that is done by the MP3 encoder which uses masking thresholds for different frequency band. That's the dominating noise source at low frequencies (the noise is masked by the tone).
2. There is also quite a bit of widening of the main lobe which is due to the masking thresholds on the adjacent bands.
3. The added noise appears to be white. At low frequencies it's masked by the MP3 encoder noise, but above the main peak it's clearly visible
4. We can also see that the Encoder has a hard stop at 16 kHz.

The more tricky part would be to deduce the noise level. I looks like the noise floor is at -60dB, but that's NOT the case. For this type of spectral analysis the "visible" SNR is a function of the FFT size. If you double the FFT size, the amplitude of the peak will increase by 6dB whereas the noise floor will increase only by 3dB.

The reason why your pictures are not showing this is probably because your FFT size is way too long. All the noise energy is spread out over half a million frequency bins where as the sine wave is just in a single bin.

If you want the actual SNR it's easy enough to calculate it directly in the time domain.

$$ SNR = 10\cdot \log_{10} \frac{<(x_{noisy}-x_{clean})^2>}{<(x_{clean})^2>} $$

Answer (score 0):

I can't see or hear any difference between the two MP3 files.

If I load both up into matlab and plot the first 10,000 points, they are identical.

[image: Exactly the same plots from both MP3 files.]

Doing:

```matlab
sine = audioread("sine.mp3");
sine_noisy = audioread("sine_noisy.mp3");
10*log10(sum(abs(sine-sine_noisy).^2)/sum(abs(sine).^2))

error = sine-sine_noisy;

semilogy(abs(fft(error)))
```

I get

-41.5750

decibels as a noise-to-signal ratio... which is relatively clean.

Following @Juha P's advice, I've plotted the spectrum of the error:

[image: Spectrum of the error.]

It does looked shaped (flat for much of the frequency range).

Comment: Audacity shows (after inverting the original track and mixing the tracks) : https://postimg.cc/TLyXX92L

Comment: @JuhaP Thanks! Yes, there is something there, but it's quite low down.  My hearing isn't the best and even with headset I couldn't tell the difference. :-)